# Lightweight method to cache some text with LAMP

Tags: database, caching, lamp

I have a symfony website running on the standard LAMP setup.

I need to store about 400 bytes (the result of a JSON query, actually). the result for this query fails often (out of my hands). I want to cache this somehow. what is the easiest, cleanest, lightest way to do this?

I have a MySQL database that's being used by my models, so I could hypothetically use this. but is there a simpler way that I don't know about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php).  The biggest thing you need to remember is that it's a cache, and you should be able to cope with it expiring at any time.

There are many tutorials and books available.

Comment: thats what I'm thinking, actually. just wanted to see if there is anything else :)

Answer (score 1):

Well you could write it to a file!.

```
$dmp = fopen ("c:\temp\dumpquery" . time() . ".txt", "w');
fwrite ($dmp,$yourquery);
fclose($dmp);
```

Comment: True, it fulfils the "easiest" adn "lightest" criteria, but its perhaps not the most elegent solution.